# Spree property filters can't work together

Tags: filtering, spree, product

I have 2 Product property Filters in my Spree 3.0 store application

```
  Spree::Product.add_search_scope :gender_any do |*opts|
    conds = opts.map {|o| ProductFilters.gender_filter[:conds][o]}.reject { |c| c.nil? }
    scope = conds.shift
    conds.each do |new_scope|
      scope = scope.or(new_scope)
    end
    Spree::Product.with_property('Пол').where(scope)
  end

  def ProductFilters.gender_filter
    gender_property = Spree::Property.find_by(name: 'Gender')
    genders = gender_property ? Spree::ProductProperty.where(property_id: gender_property.id).pluck(:value).uniq.map(&:to_s) : []
    pp = Spree::ProductProperty.arel_table
    conds = Hash[*genders.map { |b| [b, pp[:value].eq(b)] }.flatten]
    {
        name:   'Gender',
        scope:  :gender_any,
        conds:  conds,
        labels: (genders.sort).map { |k| [k, k] }
    }
  end

  Spree::Product.add_search_scope :type_any do |*opts|
    conds = opts.map {|o| ProductFilters.type_filter[:conds][o]}.reject { |c| c.nil? }
    scope = conds.shift
    conds.each do |new_scope|
      scope = scope.or(new_scope)
    end
    Spree::Product.with_property('Type').where(scope)
  end

  def ProductFilters.type_filter
    property = Spree::Property.find_by(name: 'Тип')
    values = property ? Spree::ProductProperty.where(property_id: property.id).pluck(:value).uniq.map(&:to_s) : []
    pp = Spree::ProductProperty.arel_table
    conds = Hash[*values.map { |b| [b, pp[:value].eq(b)] }.flatten]
    {
        name:   'Type',
        scope:  :type_any,
        conds:  conds,
        labels: (values.sort).map { |k| [k, k] }
    }
  end
```

This in Gender and Product type filters.

When filter using with only one parameter, like so:

- Gender : Male

Filter work normal.

- Type: Shirt

Filter work normal.

If I use filter with 2 parameters:

- Gender: Male
- Type: Shirt

Filter return zero items.
How to fix this?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: Compared to other platforms I think it sucks. However here is a solution https://gist.github.com/maxivak/cc73b88699c9c6b45a95